# format JSON for fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, fullcalendar

So I've got a data set being loading via a get request which returns JSON, full calendar is calling this data via the 'event:' property. In full calendar the events are formatted like

```
{
  title: 'My Event',
  start: '2010-01-01',
  description: 'This is a cool event'
}
```

But my data doesn't have such columns, for example, I would like the ;title' property of an event to be a concatenated string made of the my columns 'firstname' and 'lastname', does full calendar have a way of overriding the default properties of an event? so changing 'start' to 'out_date', 'out_date' being a column in my table. Or would I have to go through all of the json and change the keys when full calendar loads it?

Comment: what is full_calendar?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi https://fullcalendar.io

Comment: can you add a *snippet* of the controller where you get the data?

Comment: I have sort of sorted this this out, I looped through the data set and change the keys in the array, then converted to JSON, I thought there would be a way to change the keys on the fly with full calendar.

Comment: The other option if you don't want to change it server-side, you can use [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) with fullcalendar to get it in the format required